# Gradle - Sync does not work if module declared without path and configuration

Tags: android-studio, gradle

We have several in-house libs that we want to import a local dependency. However if we do:

```
implementation project(':moduleA')
```

Android Studio will not sync the project:

```
CONFIGURE SUCCESSFUL in 5s
ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@develop/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project moduleA
```

However strangely enough compilation does work (through Android Studio and on the console).

To make it sync in Android Studio, it has to be declared like this:

```
implementation project(path: ':moduleA', configuration: 'default')
```

But the problem with the above is that it will no longer import the dependencies for `moduleA`.

How to declare the module so that it will both sync and import the dependencies?